# Downloading Images from Pixiv, Header problems

Tags: html, header

I'm having trouble downloading images from pixiv.net with an AutoHotKey script I'm working on. I'm able to login to the site and get the correct cookies and also download the HTML for the page with a larger image, but I can't download the image itself. The server usually returns this header:

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>
> Server: nginx
>
> Date: Sat, 23 Jan 2016 13:35:12
>
> GMT Content-Type: text/html
>
> Content-Length: 162
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Then after I learned what "nosniff" actually was, I tried adding this to the request header:

> Accept: image/jpeg

which gave a response header of:

> HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable
>
> Server: nginx Date: Sat,
>
> 23 Jan 2016 22:24:53 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Content-Length: 206
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Expires: Sun, 22 Jan 2017 22:24:53 GMT
>
> Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
>
> Content-Range: bytes */56831
>
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

I've also tried an experiment in firefox with private browsing mode to try and isolate the problem. I login like normal and go to submission's page, [such as this](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=54878656)
Then I tried to open the [full size image url](http://i1.pixiv.net/img-original/img/2016/01/24/09/37/37/54878656_p0.png) in another tab. That gives a 403. Clicking the medium size image to load the full size and then trying to refresh the other "403" tab still gives a 403. BUT, when I right-click and "view image", then try to refresh the "403" tab then it loads the image like it supposed to.

I've tried using fiddler and httpfox to see if any cookies are added, but it was actually missing some rather than having anything added. Adding a referer, user-agent,and even phpsessid doesn't seem to have any affect at all. Only the mime type seemed to do anything different.

Does anyone know what I might be missing in the header?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Referer` field in request headers. `Referer` should be exist on Pixiv. `User-Agent` is not required.